# Google Sheets: find value and replace entire cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a value in a cell like this:

```
testemail@gmail.com

MS - Business
```

It's three lines. I'd like to search for "MS -" and replace the entire cell with:

```
MS
```

The regular expression:

```
.*MS -*.
```

only works for the third line. Not all three lines when using search and replace. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what formula are you using ? or are you doing that in a JS script ?

Comment: Just using the search and replace function within Google Sheets.

Comment: As @Wiktor suggested (I guess he's preparing an asnwer): http://i.imgur.com/hRNKfNw.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In a formula**, you can use the inline DOTALL modifier `(?s)` to make `.` match any character including a newline (that is supported by [RE2 regex engine](https://re2.googlecode.com/hg/doc/syntax.html)):

```
"(?s).*MS *-.*"
```

[image]

```
            \/
```

[image]

**In the *Search and Replace* dialog**, you can use JS-like regex with the opposite shorthand character classes inside a character class:

```
[\s\S]*MS -[\s\S]*
```

[image]

Comment: Doesnt work, your first suggestion did; feel free to use that gif xD

Comment: Oh, and he's not using a formula, just the plain find & replace `ctrl+H`

Comment: I see now, I did not read all the comments. Google and all its products are really weird as you can have various (sub)flavors in one product.